# Grep/sed between two strings

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have this code at the moment

```
cat -n rfile | sed -n '/"semantic_url":"/,/","/p'
```

where rfile is a file with a lot of text. I am trying to extract everything between every

```
"semantic_url":"
```

(including the double quotes and the last double quote.)

and the next pattern like this:

```
","
```

I am not certain what I am doing wrong. I have been working on it for a long time, reading man page after man page and googling. What am I doing wrong?

It is not only giving me back what's between those patterns. It gives me the whole thing back.

Input Example.

```
"semantic_url":"number1","thisorthat"semantic_url":"number2","somecode"semantic_url":"number3","somemorecode
```

Output example

```
 number1, number2, number3
```

Comment: Add some example input and expected output.

Comment: Your quotes don't match up in pairs...every other colon is in quotes, for example.

Comment: @Wildcard - i don't think its relevant to the question except that it might make it harder. the point - as i took it - is that the delimiters are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -netP -e's/"semantic_url":"\([^"]*\)","/\n\1\n/;D' \
    -e:P  -e'P;D' <in >out
```

...if I understand your description of the problem, and if the starting and ending quotes are located on the same line, and so long as the bits between `"semantic_url":"` and `","` do not contain a double-quote, then that will print only your delimit strings and all that falls between each pair for every pair found on a line at one pair per output line.

If you want the output lines joined I could write a little thing for that, but it may be easier to just add another `sed`:

```
sed -netP -e's/"semantic_url":"\([^"]*\)","/\n \1\n/;D' \
    -e:P  -e'P;//!=;D' <in|\
sed -e'/^[^ ].*/!{H;d;}'   \
    -e's///;x;s/\n.//;s//,/g'
```

I fed the above pipeline input like:

```
"semantic_url":"number1","thisorthat"semantic_url":"number2","somecode"semantic_url":"number3","somemorecode
"semantic_url":"number4","thisorthat"semantic_url":"number5","somecode"semantic_url":"number6","somemorecode
"semantic_url":"number7","thisorthat"semantic_url":"number8","somecode"semantic_url":"number9","somemorecode
```

And it printed:

```
number1,number2,number3
number4,number5,number6
number7,number8,number9
```

Comment: But what if I have many many of them on one line due to laziness?

I only get returned ONE example. And for some reason it includes the 

"semantic_url":" and "," parts which I really want to remove.

I get returned:
 
 

**"semantic_url":"ONE-OF-THE-HUNDRED-THINGS-I-WANT-TO-KEEP","** but I only want and need the **ONE-OF-THE-HUNDRED-THINGS-I-WANT-TO-KEEP** part

Comment: @KaizervonMaanen - You said you wanted the quotes! How should I know which? you've got 5 or 6 of them in your strings! It will work for as many as you might have on any line  - but every string it extracts from a single line will be written out on its own line. So: `"semantic_url":"some stuff","  a whole bunch of other stuf "semantic_url":"more stuff again","` will print `some_stuff`and `more stuff again` but each on a new output line.

Comment: Sorry, I added examples of input and expected output. You misunderstood what I meant, I probably did not explain myself properly

Comment: @KaizervonMaanen - this will *now* drop the delimit strings - but it will still print each found string on a separate output line. is that a problem? Your example is output like `number1\nnumber2\nnumber3`

Comment: no, that's fine.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Where do you learn all that extra stuff?

Comment: @KaizervonMaanen - I fixed the comma thing. Mostly here - i like `sed` and silly questions like this teach me stuff. i've got a lot of `sed` answers - most of its ok if you wanna look at it. you can learn a lot here - it's how i did.

Comment: Whoa, @mikeserv, are you code golfing or what?  (1) You're using `-netP` which appears to be a bunch of options but is actually code (I think).  (2) You're using `P` as a *label name* which just confuses things.  (I usually use `k` or `z` or something that can't be mistaken for a command.)

Comment: How about this totally valid `sed` command: `sed -e 's;q;bt\;:d;p;:P' -nen '-ep' -e s:b\;H\\\;x\\\;:P\;:g\;:s -e s\\\;\\bs\;q\\p\;tP`  Try reading THAT one.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard - does it work? maybe it could be cleaned up - but i almost always lead with `-optionsexecutionlabel` - and i generally name my branch labels for what i mean to happen when i branch. I don't find it confusing - i can understand why others might - but i don't think that is perfectly valid - i think there are too many backslashes. in general i avoid unnecessarily quoting an argument because its harder to machine parse later - backslashes are easy - they go right before the quoted character. its not golfed - each line is a single loop.

Comment: Try running mine; it doesn't throw an error.  Some of the backslashes are delimiters to the `s` command and some are escaping other characters that are otherwise used as delimiters.  :P  Plus most of the `old/new` strings in `s` commands are written to look like `sed` commands, for extra confusion.  The *slightly* more readable (i.e. not deliberately obfuscated) version is: `sed -n -e 's@q@bt;:d@p;:P' -e 'n;p;s@b;H\;x\;@P;@g;:s' -e 's@;@bs;q@p;tP'`  Your code isn't too confusing, (I upvoted it—it's clever), but I usually try for readability as a key goal.

Comment: (To clarify: my sed command is not an answer at all, nor does it do anything useful; it's just an example of obfuscated sed code.)

Comment: @Wildcard - whats the point of `s@b;H\;x\;@`? those backslashes just get eaten, i think. and this isn't what my sed scripts look like - i put mine in files with a `sed` hashbang. i was doing these answers about a year before i learned that if you answer a question and the asker cannot simply *`CTRL+C`*  - *`SHIFT+INSERT`* -  *`RETURN`* to run your suggestion then there's a good chance they'll never even get to see how it performs in the first place. I don't do `\n` in the RHS *except* here - and it usually comes with caveats but i left it out this time, i guess.

Comment: As mentioned, it is just an example of unreadable-but-valid `sed` code (so no real "point").  :)  But no, those backslashes don't get eaten, because they're in a `s` command, where they are literal backslashes unless they are preceding an instance of the `s` command's delimiter.  Point taken about copy-paste solutions and I didn't mean to sound critical, though I see how it came across that way.  Sorry about that.  ;)  I've learned a lot from you on this site, by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33076/discussion-between-wildcard-and-mikeserv).

Comment: @Wildcard - anyway - you were right. it was way too complicated - i made it too hard. i thought about it again, and i realized it could be much more simple. thank you.